# anchor tag in my flex container breaks my layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i want the second block quote element to look like the first one but with a clickable name and pic so i wrap them in an anchor tag it didn't behave like i wanted the text sits under the image. making the anchor tag a flex container fixes my problem i just don't understand why it behaves like that.

```
.review__user a {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

demo is right here [pen](https://codepen.io/lein/pen/OdqBQw)

Comment: just *wrap* your `review__user-name` with the `a` element...

Comment: :facepalm idk why making this so complicated.. stupid me

Answer (score 0):

```
.review__user, .review__user > a{
display: flex;
width:100%;
align-items: center;
```

}

Try this, it will solve your problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
.review__user a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}
```